# tcp disconnect creation on windows and linux

Tags: java, tcp

I am running a window/linux java application which connects to a server for market information.  I'm trying to test our re-connect logic and don't have access to bouncing the server.  Is there a way on windows and linux to kill or interrupt a socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try unplugging your network cable :-)